# Netbeans - Unknown entity type connecting MySQL through Glassfish

Tags: java

So I have come to an hold, and need help. I don't know how to continue with this and figuerd I should ask for help. I've look up some tutorials over youtube and over the internet on how to fix my problem but no one has helpt. I've tried numerous solutions but no one has worked.

The thing I'm trying to do is a Case Managment system(Simple dummy cms not a big one), i'm trying to expand my knowledge in java coding. The csm should run over a webapplication that will connect to MySQL, over the webapplication you should be able to add & edit. I went for creating it simply in JSP and Servlet.

I belive I've done right when it comes to the code but I'm not 100% sure since i'm not managing to run the webapp. My problem is that i'm getting an error fram Glassfish "Error compiling the query [Ärende.getAll: SELECT e FROM cases e]. Unknown entity type [cases]". I've searched the net and found that it's the SQL query that is wrong. But whatever I trie I cant get it to work.

I'm trying to access the database (which is mydb) through persistence.xml.

Here is my code

First we have setter and getter (Also some words are written in Swedish so I apologize if it's getting a little difficult to understand)

> @Entity 
>   @Table
>   @NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="Ärende.getAll",query = "SELECT e FROM cases e")) 
>    The Query part is the part which I belive is wrong but even if I write "Ärende e" instead it does not work
>
> ```
> public class Ärende implements Serializable {
>
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
> @Column
> private int idcases;
> @Column
> private String Namn;
> @Column
> private String Prioritet;
> @Column
> private String Status;
>
> public int getIdcases() {
>     return idcases;
> }
>
> public void setIdcases(int idcases) {
>     this.idcases = idcases;
> }
>
> public String getNamn() {
>     return Namn;
> }
>
> public void setNamn(String Namn) {
>     this.Namn = Namn;
> }
>
> public String getPrioritet() {
>     return Prioritet;
> }
>
> public void setPrioritet(String Prioritet) {
>     this.Prioritet = Prioritet;
> }
>
> public String getStatus() {
>     return Status;
> }
>
> public void setStatus(String Status) {
>     this.Status = Status;
> }
>
> public Ärende(int idcases, String Namn, String Prioritet, String Status) {
>     this.idcases = idcases;
>     this.Namn = Namn;
>     this.Prioritet = Prioritet;
>     this.Status = Status;
> }
>
> public Ärende(){} }
> ```

The Second thing I did was create "Ärende"Dao and Local

> ```
> @Stateless 
> public class ÄrendeDao implements ÄrendeDaoLocal {
> @PersistenceContext
> private EntityManager em;
>
> @Override
> public void addÄrende(Ärende ärende) {
>     em.persist(ärende);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void editÄrende(Ärende ärende) {
>     em.merge(ärende);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void deleteÄrende(int idcases) {
>     em.remove(getÄrende(idcases));
> }
>
> @Override
> public Ärende getÄrende(int idcases) {
>     return em.find(Ärende.class, idcases);
> }
>
> @Override
> public List<Ärende> getAllÄrende() {
>     return em.createNamedQuery("Ärende.getAll").getResultList();
> } }
> ```

The Local

> ```
> @Local 
> public interface ÄrendeDaoLocal {
>
> void addÄrende(Ärende ärende);
>
> void editÄrende(Ärende ärende);
>
> void deleteÄrende(int idcases);
>
> Ärende getÄrende(int idcases);
>
> List<Ärende> getAllÄrende();
>  }
> ```

Alright so after that hard process I finaly created the Servlet and then the JSP

Servlet:

> @WebServlet(name = "ÄrendeServlet", urlPatterns = {"/_rendeServlet"})
>   public class ÄrendeServlet extends HttpServlet {
>       @EJB
>       private ÄrendeDaoLocal ärendeDao;
>
> ```
> protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse >Response)
>         throws ServletException, IOException {
>         String action = request.getParameter("action");
>         String idcasesStr = request.getParameter("idcases");
>         int idcases=0;
>         if(idcasesStr!=null && !idcasesStr.equals(""))
>             idcases=Integer.parseInt(idcasesStr);
>
>
>         String Namn = request.getParameter("Namn");
>         String Prioritet = request.getParameter("Prioritet");
>         String Status = request.getParameter("Status");
>
>        Ärende ärende = new Ärende(idcases, Namn, Prioritet, Status);
>
>        if("Add".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
>            ärendeDao.addÄrende(ärende);
>        }else if("Edit".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
>            ärendeDao.editÄrende(ärende);
>        }else if("Delete".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
>            ärendeDao.deleteÄrende(idcases);
>        }else if("Search".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
>           ärende = ärendeDao.getÄrende(idcases);
>        }
>        request.setAttribute("ärende", ärende);
>        request.setAttribute("allÄrende", ärendeDao.getAllÄrende());
>        request.getRequestDispatcher("ärendeinfo.jsp").forward(request,response);
>
> }
> ```

JSP

> ```
>     <form action="./ÄrendeServlet" method="POST">
>             <td>Ärende ID</td>
>             <td><input type="text" name="idcases" value="${ärende.idcases}" /></td>
>             <td>Namn</td>
>             <td><input type="text" name="Namn" value="${ärende.Namn}" /></td>
>             <td>Prioritet</td>
>             <td><input type="text" name="Prioritet" value="${ärende.Prioritet}" /> 
>             <td><input type="text" name="Status" value="${ärende.Status}" /></td>
>                 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
>                 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
>                 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
>                 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" />
> ```

--- Same JSP this is just going to list all the cases below ---

> ```
>             <th>Ärende ID</th>
>             <th>Namn</th>
>             <th>Prioritet</th>
>             <th>Status</th>
>             <c:forEach items="${allÄrende}" var="stud">
>                 <tr>
>                     <td>${stud.idcases}</td>
>                     <td>${stud.Namn}</td>
>                     <td>${stud.Prioritet}</td>
>                     <td>${stud.Status}</td>
>                 </tr>
>             </c:forEach>
> ```

well that is all for the code part, and now When I try to runt it I get the error, my database is connected over glassfish JDBC and it does PING correctly.

Information about the database:
the database tabel name that i'm trying to connect to is called: cases
the database name is: mydb
the hostname: root
password is:vedo

I'm  also whondering if I should do anything more with the persistence.xml, because I have not writen anything in the persistence.xml.

Can someone help me out with this? 
Sorry for throwing a lot of information in just one post but wanted to show evrething so that someone can throw me in the right direction.

Sorry for any misspelling.

Comment: Could you please trim down your code to what is necessary to understand your question?

Comment: Yes I do apologize for that first time posting and trying to get a hang over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity 
@Table 
@NamedQueries(
    @NamedQuery(name="Ärende.getAll",query = "SELECT e FROM cases e")
) 
public class Ärende implements Serializable
```

The problem is, that your class is called Ärende, but in your named query you use cases. The named query should be:

```
    @NamedQuery(name="Ärende.getAll",query = "SELECT e FROM Ärende e")
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I have tried that Query and do still get the same error."  Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-8034] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Ärende.getAll: SELECT e FROM Ärende e]. Unknown entity type [rende].. Please see server.log for more details. " Does this have to do anything that my table name is called Cases, and that I have writen all the code as "Ärende".

Comment: The problem is with the special character in your entity name. Try renaming your entity and update the query. For example: `@Entity(name="Cases")` and `@NamedQuery(name="Ärende.getAll",query = "SELECT e FROM Cases e")`.

Comment: When you are using JPA queries, the entity name (the name specified in @Entity or by default the class name) will be used. The name, schema and catalog of the table can be specified in the @Table annotation. By default (depending on JPA provider and the DB), the class name is also used for table name by default. So, if your table is named Cases, you should add `@Table(name = "Cases")`

Comment: Well I'm not getting the same error anymore so that is a really good progress, and thanks for the information I've totaly learned something new. But not I'm stuck with something really wierd. The Glassfish complains when I run it that my "Application name "ÄrendeWebApplication" is already in use" which is really strange, since I dont have any project named the same.